# Returning complex data objects from Spring Boot Controllers

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, httpresponse, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to return a complex data object which has interface aggregated in it as shown below,

```
public class ReportHolder extends AbstractDataObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 51617699878708757349465L;
    static {
        com.scmn.gjow.util.XMLConverter.registerDataObjectClass(com.scmn.gjow.dto.ReportHolder.class);
    }

    private List productKeys;
    **private ReportHeader reportHeader;**
    private BlackedOutDestination[] blackedOutDestinations;
    private TabOccurrences tabsOccurrencesData;
    
    public ReportHolder(ReportHeader reportHeader, List productKeys)
    {
        this.reportHeader = reportHeader;
        this.productKeys = productKeys;
    }
    
    public ReportHeader getReportHeader()
    {
        return reportHeader;
    }

    public ReportHolder(List productKeys) {
        this.productKeys = productKeys;
    }

    public List getProductKeys() {
        return productKeys;
    }

    public void setProductKeys(List productKeys) {
        this.productKeys = productKeys;
    }

    public BlackedOutDestination[] getBlackedOutDestinations() {
        return blackedOutDestinations;
    }

    public void setBlackedOutDestinations(BlackedOutDestination[] blackedOutDestinations) {
        this.blackedOutDestinations = blackedOutDestinations;
    }

    public TabOccurrences getTabsOccurrencesData() {
        return tabsOccurrencesData;
    }

    public void setTabsOccurrencesData(TabOccurrences tabsOccurrencesData) {
        this.tabsOccurrencesData = tabsOccurrencesData;
    }
}
```

And the Report Header sub class is an interface as below,

```
public interface ReportHeader extends DataObjectWithChangeLog,Validatable,SensitiveLogSupported, Cloneable
{
   
    public static final String LOA_FIELD                           = "loaExist";
    public static final String INCIDENT_NUM_FIELD                  = "incidentNum";

    void validate(Validator validator);

    void update(ReportHeader report);
    
    String getSourceText1();

    void setSourceText1(String sourceText);

    String getSourceText2();

    void setSourceText2(String sourceText);

    T1AIndicator getT1AIndicator();

    void setT1AIndicator(T1AIndicator indicator);

    ReportSource getRptSource();

    void setRptSource(ReportSource rptSource);
   
}
```

When I remove the ReportHeader object from this ReportHolder I don't get any exception. But I need it to be returned from my controller.
When I try to return this **Report Holder **object from controller with this Report Header I get
the below exception:

```
Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:530) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:363) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.sendServerError(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:552) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:442) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:209) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:142) [spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) [spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1332) [spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1143) [spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) [spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) [spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
```

Do I need to add HttpMessageConverters or is there any way to return this kind of Data Object.
How to resolve this exception.

Comment: If anyone has any idea please comment it out

Answer (score 0):

Java objects only exists in the memory. There is no way to transfer them outside the memory over an HTTP request, or any other kind of request.

What you could do is serialize the request in a way that can be understood and parsed from the client to reconstruct a similar object. Traditional Java serialization is very fragile and not really helpful and would be a bad idea for this use case.

The traditional way of solving it for REST APIs/HTTP requests this is to translate the Java object into a JSON document. You could use XML or some other standard format if you prefer.

Comment: I'm trying to return my ReportHolder dataobject in Stringified XML format, but my need is to return them as Data Object in the HTTP Response. Will Http Message Converters work?

Comment: What is a Data Object here?

Comment: I just want to return them (HTTP Response) as a POJO (ReportHolder class with interfaces) instead of stringified XML data. Will it be possible ?

Comment: It is technically possible to serialize them but it causes lots of issues, will break when anyone changes the Java version and potentially can cause security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I'm fine with security as we are not handling any sensitive data can you give me some leads on how to serialize

Comment: I don't believe it makes sense to serialize Java objects for this but if you have to do it you should learn about Java serialization first https://data-flair.training/blogs/serialization-and-deserialization-in-java/, https://brightsec.com/blog/deserialization-in-java/, then read a tutorial. About security even if the data is not critical an attacker can get access to any other information of the server or may the server itself.